# Custom functionality for content saved to database

Tags: databases

I'm creating a turn-based game where I store most of my content in a database (enemies, items, npcs, location data, etc). This allows me to update the content easily without needing to rebuild anything.

I'm wondering if there is a way to safely link something like an enemy db instance to some hardcoded custom functionality. For example, maybe at the start of combat a certain enemy casts a specific spell or yells something.

I could look up a custom behavior file based on an enemy name or db id, but then if it changed that functionality would break. I could have a field for uploading a custom behavior script but that could introduce a slew of issues.

tl;dr; Are there standard patterns for adding custom functionality to content that is saved/loaded from a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a field dedicated to store the name of the script, and lookup the script by that.

Unlike finding the script by the name or id of the entity, you will be able to have multiple that use the same script. Plus, you can change the name of the entity without unlinking the script.

Answer (score 0):

What Theraot said is basically true. You are putting data first in your game. The entities: monsters, items and weapons are defined by their data and, their attributes.
Now if you want to add "special attributes", you could simply list those by name in a comma separated string.
If I totally agree with Theraot answer why did I bother to write one?

1. You should make a tool for adding and removing these behaviors. If you do this by hand you might have very strange typos and annoying behaviors.
2. You could consider using reflection to load the scripts/class/method by name.
3. Consider using snail case naming for these like `yell_horde` or `attack_kick` so you'll know what type of behavior you want to add to the entity.

Comment: By reflection I mean specifically getting a method by it's `String` name. In essence what you are doing is assigned behaviors as components to an entity.